# Read XML in JAVA

Tags: java, xml

I would like to read my XML in JAVA

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<myapp version="1.0">
<photo_information>
  <date>2016/08/20</date>
  <time>17:21:59</time>
  <user_data></user_data>
  <prints>1</prints>
  <photos>
    <photo image="1">IMG_0001.JPG</photo>
    <photo image="2">IMG_0002.JPG</photo>
    <photo image="3">IMG_0003.JPG</photo>
    <photo image="4">IMG_0004.JPG</photo>
    <output>prints\160820_172159.jpg</output>
  </photos>
</photo_information>
</myapp>
```

I need the following infos:

- prints
- All images (IMG_0001.JPG, IMG_0002.JPG, IMG_0003.JPG, IMG_0004.JPG)
- Output (prints\160820_172159.jpg)

I tried this with this code but it´s not working:

```
 package my.app.test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.jdom.Document;
import org.jdom.Element;
import org.jdom.JDOMException;
import org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder;
import org.jdom.output.XMLOutputter;

public class TestXML {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Document doc = null;

        String filePath = "/myPath/IMG_0001.xml";
        File f = new File(filePath);

        try {

            SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
            doc = builder.build(f);
            XMLOutputter fmt = new XMLOutputter();


            fmt.output(doc, System.out);


            Element element = doc.getRootElement();
            System.out.println("\nWurzelelement: " + element);


            System.out.println("Wurzelelementname: " + element.getName());


            List alleKinder = (List) element.getChildren();
            System.out.println("Erstes Kindelement: "
                    + ((Element) alleKinder.get(0)).getName());


            List benannteKinder = element.getChildren("photos");


            System.out.println("benanntes Kindelement: "
                    + ((Element) benannteKinder.get(0)).getName());


            Element kind = element.getChild("bw_mode");
            System.out.println("Photo: " + kind.getValue());


            Element kind2 = element.getChild("photo");
            System.out.println("Photo: " + kind2.getAttributeValue("name"));
        } catch (JDOMException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the result you get right now? any exception? Please try to describe what your problem is

Comment: you shouldnt be allowed to put any more questions without giving credit to previous questions - but this stupid site allows it

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to create a schema and use JAXB to unmarshall incoming XML into java object and read it like POJO.

If you don't know how to create schema then you can use some online tool to get help - http://xmlgrid.net/xml2xsd.html

You will then have to generate Java objects using ANT.

Yes! Hell lot of work for such a simple problem but this is how xmls should be parsed in Java.

**Remember !!! XML is like a war. If it isn't helping you then most probably you are not using it enough.**

Comment: but when you have to parse very big XML, stream parsers may be useful since "unmarshall incoming XML into java object and read it like POJO" will be very slow..

Comment: How 'big' and how 'long' you mean? Given the data in the question, I don't think he is going to receive huge XMLs and the way I mentioned is the standard way. There might be exceptions though based on case to case. If data is huge and latency is low then obviously we have different ways.

Comment: the simplest way  to generate java objects from schema is XJC -d src -p com.test.schema schema.xsd rather than ANT tasks.

Comment: Yeah.. I mean "long" :)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to your approach you could take a look at the library xstream [xstream](http://x-stream.github.io/).

This library enables you to serialize and deserialize objects to xml code.

Your first step is to model a class that contains all fields of your photo information. Normally you would call it PhotoInformation:

```
class PhotoInformation {
   LocalDate date;
   LocalTime time;
   UserData userData;
   int prints;
   Photos photos;
}
```

In addition you need to create a few other classes: UserData and Photos.

In the next step you need to set up the parser of xstream to fill your objects with the content from the xml file.
For that you'll find a tutorial [here](http://x-stream.github.io/alias-tutorial.html) or [here](http://x-stream.github.io/annotations-tutorial.html) if you like annotations.

Comment: Is there no other possibility?

Comment: What do you mean?
You need to tell xstream what xml-value needs to be written in which field in the java-object. For that you need some kind of definition-code.
This definition code can either be done by annotations or through corresponding methods of a XStreak object.

Comment: With jdom for example like in my first post?

Answer (score 0):

Using JAXB Parsing would be a better option. To parse this you would have to make Classes.

//Add this to your pom in plugins

```
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
```

Making the following classes

```
        @XmlRootElement(name = "myapp")
        class MyApp{
        PhotoInformation[] photoInformation;

        @XmlElement(name = "photo_information")
        public PhotoInformation getPhotoInformation() {
            return individuals;
        }

        public void setPhotoInformation(Individuals photoInformation) {
            this.individuals = individuals;
        }
    }
@XmlRootElement(name= "photo_Information")
class PhotoInformation {
   LocalDate date;
   LocalTime time;
   UserData userData;
   int prints;
   Photos[] photos;
//add getters and setters for the above variables with the @XmlElement Annotations and correct tag name
}

@XmlRootElement(name= "photo")
class Photo{
String photo;
//add getter and setter for the above variables with the @XmlElement Annotations and correct tag name
}
```

for UnMarshalling(Parsing) the file

```
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyApp.class);
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    File XMLfile = new File(folderPath);
    myApp myapp = (myApp) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(XMLfile);
```

Through myapp object you will be able to access the rest of the tags that inside the myApp class and you can further iterate through photo_information and have access to photos.

I hope this helps